# Strange Java Class-Path/Class-Loader behaviour

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have a very strange Java class path behaviour when loading a class file which references other classes which are not available at runtime.

Loading a class which has a (at runtime untouched method) which calls a constructor of another class with a parameter that is casted to a class which inherits the class of the parameter causes a class not found exception of the paramter class if only the class to load but no other classes referenced in methods of that class is in class path.

I am using following java:

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
(Windows Server 2008 R2)
```

Here is a sample:

```
public class A
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("it works");
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    new B((D)null);
  }
}

public class B
{
  public B(C c) {
  }
}

public class C
{
}


public class D extends C
{
}
```

Now i compile the classes, and if i execute the class A with all class files in the class path, it yields "it works".

If i remove all classes excepet class A from the class path, following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: A.  Program will exit.
```

although class C should never be needed at runtime.

Following constellation works (replaced "new B((D)null)" in class A):

```
public class A
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("it works");
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    D d = (D)null;
    d.toString();
    B b = (B)null;
    b.toString();
    new B(null);
  }
}

public class B
{
  public B(C c) {
  }
}

public class C
{
}


public class D extends C
{
}
```

Following constellation also works (cast to C instead of D; C does not inherit any class)

```
public class A
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("it works");
  }

  public void foo()
  {
    new B((C)null);
  }
}

public class B
{
  public B(C c) {
  }
}

public class C
{
}


public class D extends C
{
}
```

Is this an expected behaviour or a Java bug?

Comment: `although class C should never be needed at runtime.`  It most certainly is needed at runtime.  D is a C, so it is logically impossible to say C is not needed.

Comment: this is true, but if i explicitly cast to C which is also not available at runtime, it works.
the classes B, C and D should never be get loaded as though the main method only has a println but nothing else, and foo gets never called.

Comment: Are you doing this through an IDE or the command line? Try it in both environments, sometimes Eclipse likes to be "helpful"

Comment: i am simply using `javac *.java`, `java A` and for the test case i simply delete the files B.class, C.class and D.class.

Answer (score 1):

[refer section 5.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html), if "If the value at run time is null, then the cast is allowed", that is why null casting working.

Comment: null casting is always working, yes. but the problem is not about casting null. my main question is why the class loader thinks that it needs to load class C although foo is never called at runtime. and why it load class C if i pass an argument **derived vom class C, but not C directly**.
`public void foo() { new B(new C()) }` ALSO WORKS; `public void foo() { new B(new D()) }` DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through the JSR but my guess would be that when interpreter interprets a class file it won't do only required methods, it would do all. In this case `A` is needed and if `foo()` is also interpreted then `C` would be needed. All this should be happening at the time when `A` is loaded. So the error..

Comment: i know that C is indirectly needed. but why does    D d = (D)null;
    `d.toString();
    B b = (B)null;
    b.toString();`

and

`new B((C)null);`

work? all these versions require the classes B, C and D, too.

Comment: refer section 5.5, if "If the value at run time is null, then the cast is allowed" http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html